# MyHDL VHDL conversion: no index value can belong to null index range

Tags: python, vhdl, myhdl

For an algorithm I implemented and successfully converted to VHDL, I get this error during the "Static elaboration of top level VHDL design":

> no index value can belong to null index range

I boiled the code down to the essential part (you might recognize a cordic processor).

```
import myhdl
from myhdl import enum, intbv, always_comb, always_seq, always, instance, Signal, ResetSignal, Simulation, delay, StopSimulation
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase


# input bit width
BIT_IN = 16

########################################################
#                  IMPLEMENTATION                      #
########################################################

def NullIndex(clk, reset):

  R2P_W = 16

  # nr of iterations equals nr of significant input bits
  R2P_N = R2P_W-1

  R2P_LIMIT = 2**(R2P_W+1)

  x = [Signal(intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT)) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
  y = [Signal(intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT)) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
  z = [Signal(intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT)) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]

  @always_seq(clk.posedge, reset=reset)
  def processor():
      dx = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
      dy = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
      dz = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]

      # actual algorithm
      # starting vector
      x[0].next = 42
      y[0].next = 42
      z[0].next = 0

      # connect all stages of the pipeline where stage 1 has been defined by the starting conditions above
      for i in range(0, R2P_N):
          # shifting performs the 2**(-i) operation
          dx[i+1][:] = x[i] >> i
          dy[i+1][:] = y[i] >> i
          dz[i+1][:] = 42 #don't worry, normally not a constant
          if (y[i] > 0):
              x[i+1].next = x[i] + dy[i+1]
              y[i+1].next = y[i] - dx[i+1]
              z[i+1].next = z[i] + dz[i+1]
          else:
              x[i+1].next = x[i] - dy[i+1]
              y[i+1].next = y[i] + dx[i+1]
              z[i+1].next = z[i] - dz[i+1]

  return processor



########################################################
#                      TESTS                           #
########################################################

class TestNullIndex(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # input/output width
        self.m = BIT_IN
        self.limit = 2**self.m

        # signals
        self.clk = Signal(bool(0))
        self.reset = ResetSignal(0, active=1, async=True)


    def testDut(self):    
        # actual test
        def test(clk):
          for _ in range(42):
            yield clk.posedge

          raise StopSimulation

        # instances
        dut = myhdl.toVHDL( NullIndex, clk=self.clk, reset=self.reset )
        inst_test = test(self.clk)

        # clock generator
        @always(delay(1))
        def clkGen():
          self.clk.next = not self.clk

        sim = Simulation(clkGen, dut, inst_test)
        sim.run(quiet=1)




if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

The intereseting part is

```
dx = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
.
.
```

When converted to VHDL it will spit out something like that for the `d[x,y,z]` arrays:

```
type t_array_dz is array(0 to -1-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dz: t_array_dz;
type t_array_dx is array(0 to -1-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dx: t_array_dx;
type t_array_dy is array(0 to -1-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dy: t_array_dy;
```

which will eventually result in the error since the array can't be from `0` to `-1-1`. Why does this happen and what did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variables declarations, MyHDL does not seem to support having an expression in the call to `range` in the list comprehension (although it does for signal declarations).

If you change this:

```
dx = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
dy = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
dz = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(R2P_N+1)]
```

to this:

```
dx = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(16)]
dy = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(16)]
dz = [intbv(0, min=-R2P_LIMIT, max=R2P_LIMIT) for _ in range(16)]
```

Then you get the expected VHDL declarations:

```
type t_array_dz is array(0 to 16-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dz: t_array_dz;
type t_array_dx is array(0 to 16-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dx: t_array_dx;
type t_array_dy is array(0 to 16-1) of signed(17 downto 0);
variable dy: t_array_dy;
```

Comment: Can one consider this a bug? Because this is neither expected or noted at any point.

Comment: @JoVaRi To me, this does looks like a bug, yes. Keep in mind I am in no way a MyHDL expert (I installed it for the first time to answer this question) and in particular, I have no idea if it is a documented limitation.